# Should we have a banner to warn about our policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chatgpt, generative-ai

SE has recently announced that [sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/162827).

This feature might be beneficial for Web Apps SE, where the community consensus seems to be that any ChatGPT-generated or similar AI-generated content should be properly referenced and verified, as per this meta post: “[Should GPT / ChatGPT generated answers be banned?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/7584)”

This would help us prevent uncited, low-quality AI-generated posts from cluttering our site.

Should we request to enable the banner?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes

We should have a banner to inform users about our policy on AI-generated content. This would dissuade users from posting uncited and/or low-quality AI-generated content in Web Apps SE.

I don’t see any drawbacks to having such a banner, and users can also dismiss the banner easily. Once dismissed, it won’t appear again for logged-in users, so it won’t be annoying.

For now, we have to pick one of the two banner text options. I propose we go with this one:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on Web Applications SE. [Learn more](https://example.com)

This option is more consistent with the community consensus that we established in the meta post: [Should GPT / ChatGPT generated answers be banned?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/7584)

Comment: The banner has been enabled. [The relevant help center article](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy) also reflects the site's policy on the matter (and it is mod-editable, in case it needs tweaking)